Anyone knows what's d rate limit of websocket after I subscribe account?
I wanna know d maximum for subscribe accounts, cuz I wanna subscribe over 1000+ accounts to monitor d account change. Thanks!!!

It depends on the service that you're using.
For example, here are the rate limits for the public RPC endpoints: https://solana.com/docs/core/clusters#mainnet-beta-rate-limits -- it looks like you'd be limited to 100MB every 30 seconds.
